# How to make navbar transparent

Tags: transparency

I have created a navbar at PureCSSMenu.com but the site doesn't offer a way to make the navbar transparent. Is it possible to tweak the code to make it transparent?

You can view the navbar below:

http://spectrum.x10.mx/navbar.html

Comment: You want either [opacity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) or [rgba](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color_value#rgba())

Comment: `opacity` is not advisable - it will also make the content, such as the actual text of the items, transparent and as such less readable. Use `rgba` on the background.

Answer (score 0):

At line 16 of your CSS, in rule `ul.pureCssMenu, ul.pureCssMenu ul`, change the background color:

```
background-color:rgba(255,255,255,0.5);
```

You now have `#ffffff` there, meaning the background is opaque white. `RGBA` notation includes an Alpha channel, in this example set to 0.5 for half-transparency. 1 is fully opaque, 0 is fully transparent.

The same applies to line 42 in the rule for the `a` elements inside, but I'd recommend deleting its background color completely - stacking semi-transparent colors is not really practical.

Comment: Thanks Niels for your reply the rgba change wasn't working so I deleted all instances of background-color:#ffffff; and that seems to work. I viewed it in Chrome and IE and it looks ok. I don't know how it will look in older browsers though but oh well, lol.

Comment: If `rgba` isn't working you need to [desperately update your browser](http://caniuse.com/css3-colors).